# How i can block requests for a specific page?

Tags: url, mod-security, joomla, block, ubuntu-14.04

I would like to completely delete or block access to a specific page in my site.

More specifically, I have seen this exploit "**Joomla COM_MEDIA Exploit**" : http://all1gat0r.blogspot.gr/2013/08/joomla-commedia-exploit.html

and from what I see, there is the page : `/index.php?option=com_media&view=images&tmpl=component&fieldid=&e_name=jform_articletext&asset=com_content&author=&folder=`

The exploit does not work on me, but anyway I want to **completely remove the above page**.
How can I do this?

Web Server : **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** ( *with installed **Mod Security2*** )
Web Site : **Joomla 3.1.5**

Answer (score 1):

As the query change the order of the parameters and be still exploitable and I am not very proficient in mod_security, I would probably use mod_rewrite to block it:

In the conf file of your apache server where all the stuff to configure Joomla are, add the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_media
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} view=images
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tmpl=component
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} fieldid
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} e_name=jform_articletext
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} asset=com_content
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} author
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} folder
RewriteRule index.php - [F,L]
```

Note: you may need to load mod_rewrite and initiate it

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
RewriteEngine on
```